# Magic missile against locks?

Tags: spells, history-of-gaming, adnd-1e

The party is about to enter the Hall of the Fire Giant King.
Although I am running a 5e game, I am rereading the 1e module to compare it and altering a few things as I go.  Today I ran across the following in the description of Snurre's treasure room:

G3 p.19 (emphasis in the original):

> These locks cannot be picked by thieves and must be opened by "bending bars" or **knock** or **magic missile** spell.

I went back and checked the descriptions of *magic missile* across various editions.  I can't find anywhere there is a version of the spell that positively says that it can be used to open locks.  In second edition, the description specifically says that it does *not* damage objects such as locks.

Aside from the reference in G3, is there anywhere else, in any edition, that *magic missile* was indicated as being a way to open locks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### AFAIK: No

From my memory and a quick search, this appears to be the only mention of Magic Missile opening locks.

Gary Gygax has [stated](http://au.pc.gamespy.com/articles/538/538820p3.html) that these modules were written before the AD&D Players Handbook which was before the Dungeon Masters Guide so it's not surprising that they contain things that didn't make the final cut.

> I did the Giants series in-between writing the Monster Manual, and before starting on the Player's Handbook.